# Getting Device's Clock including Seconds on Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, real-time-clock

I am working on a project that i need to use an Android device's clock, including seconds(importantly), on Android Studio. Is there a way to get the time and assign it to a variable and be able to do mathematical operations with it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CountDownTimer() in Java.

```
String DAY, HOUR, MINUTES, SECOND;
new CountDownTimer(setMiliseconds(15, 15, 15, 15), 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            DAY = TimeUnit.HOURS.toDays(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished)) + "";
            HOUR = (TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.DAYS.toHours(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(millisUntilFinished))) + "";
            MINUTES = (TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished))) + "";
            SECOND = (TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))) + "";

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

        }
    }.start();
```

You can access `string` variables and convert it into `int` type to use for calculation.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i will try that.